# Images out of viewport no loading

Tags: html, css, browser, disqus

Im using Disqus for comments on my Ghost template, but im having trouble with it.
The images inside Disqus `<iframe>` dont load if they are out of viewport.

Debugging I could find:

- If i remove `overflow: auto` from `.surface-container` the images appear.
- If i remove `height: 100%` from `.surface-container` the images appear.
- If you zoom out the browser the images appear.

But if i remove any of this properties the drawer not work corretcly, if you open the drawer, the site scrollsup.

It seams to be a browser issue and not a css-related problem :/

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tL5PM/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Real Scenario**](http://ghostium.oswaldoacauan.com/documentation/)</kbd>

Comment: gonna be tricky when dealing with an iframe. Just a guess but have you tried targeting the images in the iframe and setting the width to 100%; height: auto;? If this still breaks it, try setting the width of the images smaller than the width of the iframe

Comment: @MattLambert i dont think the problem are on iframe code, since removing one of the properties listed on question everything works.

Comment: @OswaldoAcauan I'm on Chrome 31.x.x, The drawer is only visible @ the top and it doesnt cause anything. And, it does intrigue me on why or how the viewport affects discuss. Can you precisely point out what fails and how?

Comment: @VivekChandra if you take a look at the fiddle, the images on disqus iframe, only load until viewport end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this:

```
main {
    overflow: visible;
}
.surface {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Update 2:**

[Fiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL5PM/3/)

Comment: well done, i will test it on real scenario latter today and give you a feedback ;)

Comment: Okay fine, if it breaks any other feature please let me know:)